# this в конструкторе С#

Tags: c#, конструктор

Добрый вечер, 
есть класс

```
class A
{
    //куча полей
    public A(int a)
    {
        //куча кода
    }
    public A(double a)
    {
        this = new A(Math.Round(a)); // вот тут мне говорит, что так нельзя
    }
}
```

Во втором конструкторе нужно реализовать абсолютно тоже самое что и в первом, но с округлённым значением. Возможно наличие большого числа полей, поэтому отдельным методом не хочу это делать.

Как бы сделать так, чтобы второй конструктор заработал? Знаю, что можно через наследование, но как без него обойтись  в данной ситуации?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте через такой синтаксис

```
public A(double a): this((int)a){}
```

Вызывать из конструктора другой конструктор через `new` череревато утечками памяти, т.к. фактически будет создано 2 объекта.

Comment: Ну, утечек памяти не будет, это ж язык со сборщиком мусора. А вот `this` присвоить не получится, он read-only.

Comment: @VladD в с получалось,  а тут не пробовал никогда)

Comment: @VladD что подрозумевается под фразой read-only? Компилятор сказал тоже самое, но я что-то не догоняю)

Comment: @koshachok: Это значит, предназначен только для чтения, а не для записи.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static A GetAObject(double a)
 {
    return new A((int)Math.Round(a)); 
 }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //а так создаём объект, тут нет слова new
        var aObj = A.GetAObject(22.222);
    }
}
```